# A GRE Math question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gre-exam

If *a* and *b* are positive integers such that the greatest common factor of $a^2b^2$ and $ab^3$ is 45, then which of the following could *b* equal?

Select **all** such integers.

```
A. 3
B. 5
C. 9
D. 15
E. 45
```

I think the answer should be **A C D E**. I went through all 5 choices and test the possibilities. It does not seem to be very efficient during testing.

Comment: Are you sure A and C are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $b$ cannot be any of the last four answers, else the gcd would not be $45$.

For example, if $b=5$, then the gcd is divisible by $25$. If $b=9$, the gcd is divisible by $81$.

Only $3$ is possible, with $a=5$.

Perhaps a little inefficient, but the same idea rules out the last four options.

Comment: thanks. i forget to think about the GCD thing...dumb :P

Comment: You are welcome. That's what practicing is for.

Comment: The gcd of (a^2)(b^2) and a(b^3) is a(b^2).Therefore  a(b^2)=45=5(3^2)=>b=3.Is this a correct approach?

Comment: @rah4927 It's not given that a and b are coprime, so $GCD(a^2b^2, ab^3) = ab^2 \times GCD(a, b)$. For example, if $a=3$ and $b=6$, then $GCD(a^2b^2, ab^3) = GCD(3^2\times6^2, 3\times6^3) = 3\times6^2\times GCD(3,6) = 3^2\times6^2 = 9\times36 = 324$, and you can also see that $GCD(3^2\times6^2, 3\times6^3) = GCD(324,648) = 324$.